# Return count on an eager-loaded relation Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have `Subject` that contains `Stack`, which contain `Question`. With every question, there are answers, and I would like to count the answers on every `Stack`, but I'm stuck.

This is what I'm trying to do, one of many solutions I have been fiddling with:

```
    $subjects = Subject::with(['stack.question', 'stack.answersCount'])->get();

    return $subjects;
```

The `Subject` model has the following relation:

```
public function stack(){
    return $this->hasMany(Stack::class);
}
```

And if we look at the `Stack` model on how the relations are built:

```
public function question(){
    return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
}

public function answers(){
    return $this->hasMany(Answers::class);
}

public function answersCount(){
    return $this->answers()->selectRaw('answer, count(*) as aggregate')->groupBy('answer');
}
```

But when I `return $subjects`, `answer_count` is empty.

```
"answers_count": []
```

It's very confusing because when I run the same query in SQL, I get non-empty results.

```
select answer, count(*) as aggregate from `answers` where `answers`.`stack_id` in ('1', '6') group by `answer`

correct 9
wrong   4
```

So how can I count all answers? And group them?

Answer (score 0):

try this way,

```
$subjects = Subject::with(['stack.question', 'stack.answersCount'])->get();
$count = $subjects->answersCount->first()->aggregate;

//count varible will have the count now you can use it as you would like to 

return $subjects;
```

Further digging can be found [here](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/)

Comment: That seems as an alternative, but would it be possible to fetch the count as I described somehow? That seems like a very clean way to do it. And I cannot understand why it doesn't work either.

Comment: I need to look into it for that I guess well have you tried this??

Comment: Yes I have tested it and it works. Im now using that concept in the blade file, but that is a n+1 issue I assume.. Is this a eloquent bug?

Comment: what you are getting in blade??

Comment: I can use it like this in a blade view file `{{ $stack->answersCount[0]->aggregate` or `{{ $stack->answersCount[1]->aggregate` depending if I want to grab `correct` or `wrong`

Comment: yeah you can better way is you can put a loop on it to get rid of [0] kind of indexes.

Comment: if you have got what you want you can upvote and accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `answersCount` relation - it's not necessary anymore, since you can use `withCount` method:

```php
$subjects = Subject::with([
    'stack.question', 
    'stack' => function ($q) {
        $q->withCount('answers');
    }
])->get();

// then on each subject you can call stack->answers_count
$subjects->first()->stack->answers_count
```

Comment: Yes that a good solution, but unfortunately I would like to group the count in `correct` and `wrong`.

Comment: So create 2 appropriate relations and call withCount for both if them

Comment: That is what I have done at the moment, I have `wrongAnswer()` and `correctAnswer()` on the stack model. And I can call `withCount()` and even attach a `where` if I want to grab a specific user.